# InvalidCastException when getting data from Database as a datetime

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I'm trying to pull some data from my Database, but when it comes to `Datetime` I get an

> InvalidCastException

This is my Database (SQL SERVER)

```
Create table Timeline(
start date,
end date
)
```

table Timeline

```
start(date)            end(date)
03/07/2020             NULL
NULL                   10/07/2020
15/07/2020             25/07/2020
```

This is my query

```
SELECT Timeline.start, Timeline.end FROM Timeline
```

This is my c# code

```
public class Timeline
{
    public DateTime? startDate;
    public DateTime? endDate;


    public static Timeline fromRow(DataRow r)
    {
        Timeline a = new Timeline();
        
        a.startDate = r.Field<DateTime?>("start");
        a.endDate = r.Field<DateTime?>("end");

        return a;
    }
}
```

When I pull a `NULL` value it works, but when I pull a real date like `03/07/2020` It gives me **InvalidCastException**. Is there a way to check the value before putting it into the variable?

Comment: Is the field in the database a string by any chance?

Comment: Which database is this? How is the table defined?

Comment: I will recreate my Database

Comment: Why does you table say not null and then you put a null into the table?

Comment: Yeah I'm not so expert you can forgive me please. I just create my table from the SQL Server management studio, I've made the `create table` following internet instructions to make clear the question, but apparently I messed it up.

Comment: Friendly FYI your naming conventions are off C# uses PascalCase over camelCase for methods classes and public fields and properties. For one I am curious how the datatable is being setup here, if the column is being set as type string could explain why cast isnt happening here, just for debugging sake try parsing the result 

i.e 

a.startDate = DateTime.TryParse(r.Field<string>("start"), out var sd) ? sd : (DateTime?)null;
...

Comment: startDate = DateTime.TryParse(r.Field<string>("start"), out var sd) ? sd : (DateTime?)null; I can't tell you what you wrote, but I can tell you that It worked. I don't know 1 year of programming I never seen an instruction like this? are you human :)   ? i.e. thank you

Comment: Glad I could help I will submit this as an answer because I believe there might be value to it for others :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is because the column type does not match up with what you are
> trying to cast to here, my guess is it is being referenced as a varchar
> type ***constructor public DataColumn (string columnName)***, which is
> fine we can just parse the date safely as a string, you may lose a few
> cycles on this but this is not 1995 anymore. If you want to cast safely
> than offer the column the correct type so ***constructor public
> DataColumn (string columnName, Type type)***

---

```
// Change Names to match C# nameing conventions
public class TimeLine
{
    // Since this class is just a strongly typed object for rows of your table values should not be able to change.
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; private set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; private set; }


    public static TimeLine FromRow(DataRow r)
    {
        // Casting will depend if we know the DataColumns type, if we dont we can just parse the string value
        return new TimeLine
        {
            StartDate = DateTime.TryParse(r.Field<string>("start"), out var sd) ? sd : (DateTime?)null,
            EndDate = DateTime.TryParse(r.Field<string>("end"), out var ed) ? ed : (DateTime?)null,
        };
    }
}
```